Drush fails after moving to another server
Upgraded site from drupal 9.5 to 10.2.2. After pulling update on server with git, everything is fine except for drush. My local machine (8.1.20) and server (8.1.21) both php 8.1, no global drush installed, I've grep'd for absolute paths in vendor, checked printenv, no old files leftover on server. I'm out of ideas, but I'm blaming composer :)
local:
$ ./vendor/bin/drush --version
Drush Commandline Tool 12.5.3.0
server:
$ ./vendor/bin/drush --version
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Drush\DrupalFinder\DrushDrupalFinder" not found in /var/www/html/xxx/www/vendor/drush/drush/src/Preflight/Preflight.php:75
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/xxx/www/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(135): Drush\Preflight\Preflight->__construct()
#1 /var/www/html/xxx/www/vendor/drush/drush/drush(4): require('...')
#2 /var/www/html/xxx/www/vendor/bin/drush(119): include('...')
#3 {main}
thrown in /var/www/html/xxx/www/vendor/drush/drush/src/Preflight/Preflight.php on line 75

Did you composer install after moving to this platform?

I did not. It has to pull from the git repo and run as is on all servers.

You are blaming Composer yet you did not run it on the server. Did you in fact look to see if the class file for Drush\DrupalFinder\DrushDrupalFinder is among the files you deployed?

Yes, it is there. All the files are there, repo includes everything but settings.php. And running git status shows no old files leftover on the server, everything is in the repo.

/var/www/html/xxx/www/vendor/drush is an unusual path, you would normally expect to find drush in /var/www/html/xxx/vendor. Maybe you have a custom solution which needs upgrading along with the Drupal version

So you think composer is making autoload files that assume site/vendor and site/www? It was originally a d8 site, but has been updated many times since without this issue.

It's not likely Composer is making assumptions, or doing anything wrong per se; barring bugs it will only do what it's told, and this doesn't sound like a bug. A typical modern Drupal installation has a composer.json above the web root, which is configured to install packages to vendor/, <webroot>/core, <webroot>/modules/contrib, and so on - seeing a <webroot>/vendor/ folder implies you're not following the usual practice, so it's difficult to advise

Sometimes it happened I've accidentally run composer install in the webroot and then had two vendor folders, one in the webroot and the real one above. This messed things up (and took a long time to find out ).

@Clive Maybe I'll run composer require drush/drush on the server and diff the changes.

Composer gets to blame me this time. I had "composer" in my .gitignore, intending to ignore www/composer, not www/vendor/composer. Having vendor in your doc root should make no difference, but you do have to check all the files into git.

This is a bug I encountered upgrading from Drupal 9. I had to downgrade to Drush 11.1.1 to get everything working again.

Sometimes the drush upgrade recreates the file with incorrect permissions. You may need to run something like this to fix it: chmod 770 vendor/bin/drush
Or... I have also seen certain upgraded drush commands fail until a drush cr is run and the failed command is retried.
